# Keep configuration inside Dockerfile? And is this image production safe?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've been browsing Docker Hub and I'm trying to determine the quality of builds.

I've got 2 questions:

## Question 1

I came accross this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/perfectweb/production/~/dockerfile/

It uses a lot of configuration rewriting inside the image, **wouldn't it be better to just copy external configuration files to the container**? Like described here: [Separate specific configuration in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383701/separate-specific-configuration-in-dockerfile).

## Question 2

One of the most-starred images for `lemp` is this one: https://hub.docker.com/r/stenote/docker-lemp/

It has a warning not to use it for production (because of the empty root password for MySQL) but I'm wondering: **are there other reasons why this image is not production safe** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wouldn't it be better to just copy external configuration files to the container?

If you copied from the disk the same `php.ini` *already* modified, that file might overwrite some of the evolution introduced by another version of php in `php.ini`.

So the current process (rewrites) allows for `php.ini` to evolve (when installing a new version of php), while keeping the rewrite visible in the Dockerfile.

> are there other reasons why this image is not production safe ?

Another reason might be that, by default, those services are accessible in http, not https.

Comment: Say I should keep a php.ini externally: when I update the image for a new PHP version, I think it should follow that I take a look at my local php.ini as well. Or is there a way for the php.ini to evolve without me noticing it?

Comment: @Oli the rewrites are there precisely to avoid having to look at a local php.ini